# Jquery using #SOMETHING in URL to fire event

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following code

```
<a href="#go">go</a>
<a href="#go2">go</a>
<a href="#go3">go</a>
<a href="#go4">go</a>

<div id="go" class=contents>1</div>
<div id="go2" class=contents>2</div>
<div id="go3" class=contents>3</div>
<div id="go4" class=contents>4</div>
```

and a script fired by anchor

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $($(this).attr('href')).css('color', 'red');
});
```

so when clicking one of the anchors i can fire some event, my question is. if i refresh the page (the URL will contain the #go tag) is it possible to catch the `#go` from the URL and fire the same event?

Comment: if you want to automatically go the part of the page I think using an anchor tag with a name would be a much easier way `<a name="go"><div>1</div></a>`

Comment: actually i wanted to fire an event inside the div @adeneo's answer works for me

Answer (score 6):

Sure, on pageload you can catch the hash and fire the event handler like this

```
$(function() {
    var hash   = window.location.hash;
    var anchor = $('[href="' + hash + '"]');

    anchor.trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: aww you were too quick for me haha

Comment: This is a very simplistic solution; for a more well-rounded one, look for the ba-bbq jquery library. It has great support for handling hashchange events.